# Using Saved Model Format from Tensorflow Lite Model Maker leads to poor prediction results

Tags: tensorflow-lite, tfjs-node

Following this [tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/g3doc/tutorials/model_maker_image_classification.ipynb) I created an simple model for image classification with Tensorflow Model Maker. I changed export format from tflite to Saved Model as I intended to use it with tfjs-node as [shown here](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/01/run-tensorflow-savedmodel-in-nodejs-directly-without-conversion.html).

```
# model.export(export_dir='.') 
model.export(export_dir='.', export_format=ExportFormat.SAVED_MODEL)
```

Testing the tflite model with an image in python returns very good results (near 95% for the desired class):

```
    import numpy as np
    from PIL import Image
    import tensorflow as tf
    
    model_file = "model.tflite"
    image_file = "my_image_name.jpg"
    
    interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=model_file)
    interpreter.allocate_tensors()
    
    input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
    output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
    
    image = Image.open(image_file)
    input_data = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)
    interpreter.invoke()
    output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
    results = np.squeeze(output_data)
    for result in results:
        print(float(result / 255.0))
        # 0.011764705882352941 0.043137254901960784 0.9490196078431372
```

When using the Saved Model format prediction results are totally different and wrong:

```
    import numpy as np
    from PIL import Image
    from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
    
    model_file = "saved_model"
    image_file = "my_image_name.jpg"
    
    model = load_model(model_file)    
    image = Image.open(image_file)
    input_tensor = np.expand_dims(image,axis=0)   
   
    predictions = model.predict(input_tensor)
    print(predictions)
    #0.0564433 0.69343865 0.25011805
```

Same problem when I use the Saved Model with tfjs-node.

1.) Do you have any idea how to fix this or where I could have a look at?
2.) What also could be helpful: Is there any supported way in tensorflow to use the tflite model with tfjs-node?

Things I tried among many other things:

- Resizing Images to the desired size before creating the model to eliminate differences in image handling
- Converting input_tensor to float32 doesn't make any difference (tf.convert_to_tensor(input_tensor, dtype=tf.float32))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using saved model, we need to nomalized and resize the model. Please refer to https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/core/task/image_preprocessing.py#L62.

The `mean_rgb` and `stddev_rgb` are in https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/core/task/model_spec/image_spec.py#L33

Comment: Thank you very much. That fixed it for my python and javascript code 

Comment: @jirzi, shall you then mark the answer as a completed?

Comment: @Gleichmut of course, done 